# MVC models don't persist in a form

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I declare a model with 4 string fields. 3 of which are read-only on the form:

```
public class HomeModel
    {
        [ReadOnly(true)]
        [DisplayName("Service Version")]
        public string ServiceVersion { get; set; }

        [ReadOnly(true)]
        [DisplayName("Session Id")]
        public string SessionId { get; set; }

        [ReadOnly(true)]
        [DisplayName("Visiting from")]
        public string Country { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Search")]
        public string SearchString { get; set; }

    }
```

I pass the model, after populating it, to my form:

```
 [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var model = new HomeModel
                            {
                                Country = "Australia",
                                SearchString = "Enter a search",
                                ServiceVersion = "0.1",
                                SessionId = "76237623763726"
                            };
           return View(model);  

        }
```

And the form is displayed as I expect:

```
<h2>Simple Lookup</h2>

@Html.LabelFor(m=>m.ServiceVersion): @Model.ServiceVersion<br/>
@Html.LabelFor(m=>m.SessionId): @Model.SessionId<br/>
@Html.LabelFor(m=>m.Country): @Model.Country<br/>
<p>
    @using(Html.BeginForm())
    {
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.SearchString)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.SearchString)
        <button type="submit" name="btnSearch">Search</button>
    }
</p>
```

But, when I submit the form, and get the model back from the form, only the value of the SearchString is populated.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(HomeModel model)
{
    return View(model);
}
```

Is it right that the other fields have been 'lost'? Does MVC not preserve the other members of the model class? And if this is expected - is there a way to re-get these? Or would I need to go back to my database, populate the model with the old values, and then use the new values from the form model?

It's possible the validity of wanting to read 'read-only' fields back from the model is questioned.. which is fair - but in the event that I find something suspect about the posted data, maybe I want to re-show the screen, and not have to re-read the data from a database again?

Comment: [ReadOnly(true)]
 means the property is readonly and hence would not be binded with the values that are posted back

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the correct behavior. Only the elements inside form will be posted to your action. Since it is posting the form so your fields should be inside the form in order to get them on your post method.

**Update**

Also, you cannot read particular field on your action method if you have taken that field readonly on your view. eg: displaying using `@Html.LabelFor`. In order to get field back on your action use `@Html.HiddenFor` if field is not to be edited.

Comment: I moved the other fields to be within the form - but get the same issue. Maybe they shouldn't be read-only in the model?

Comment: Yes exactly. You cannot get readonly fields back on your post method.

Comment: OK, thanks. So, in the event where I need to see the field as a label, AND get it back to the model, I should use both a HiddenFor (For the posting), AND a DisplayFor (for the display)?

Comment: Yes you need both if you don't want to edit your particular field. Other option is to use TempData. Set TempData on your viewload and get the same on your actionmethod.